Closing a browser session (chrome based) without missing the "restore pages" button on restart?
I'm wondering how to close a browser session the intended way (all windows at once) without missing the option to restore the previous sessions on restart, which is sometimes missing.
My issue is that if I close windows one by one, the "restore pages" button doesn't appear and there's a window limit in the recent tabs menu.
My question is specifically about being sure to not lose the session when I reopen the browser. The tabs and the state of those tabs.
The only solution I've found is to hard reboot the computer which isn't ideal.

@Destroy666 yes, using Session Buddy definitely helped. it appears browsers don't have any reliable session restoration system yet. furthermore, I'm puzzled about how modern browsers apparently couldn't store offline pages on the disk, tabs that are inactive for too long, in order to restore it without being redirected or landing on a 404 page. Session Buddy helps on the url and title but not on the content.

I would argue that hard rebooting is not really a solution at all.
The Restore Pages button is a recovery feature for when the browser shuts down improperly which is why it does not trigger for you when you close a window normally.
Chrome and Edge both have settings to continue where you left off, which is the setting to use if you want to resume after a clean shutdown of the browser.
In Chrome it is Settings | On startup | Continue where you left off
In Edge it is Settings | Start, home, and new tabs | Open tabs from the previous session.
Do note that in my experience the browser remembers the tabs that were open in the final browser window to be closed.

How to perform a clean shutdown of the browser? This setting Continue where you left off wasn't enabled on my browser. If the browser only remembers the tabs of the last window, I'm afraid this isn't useful for me, as I need all windows and tabs to be restored.

A clean shutdown of the browser just means that the browser is closed normally (clicking the Close button, choosing Exit from the File menu, etc) as opposed to something like an OS crash or End Task from task manager.  Without finding an extension or third party tool, this is the option you have available to you.  What you desire is simply not the way the feature was designed to work.

It is not possible to shutdown a chrome session cleanly and then being able to restore the previous session on the next restart? (meaning all windows and tabs, and without having them refreshed all at once)

It is, but like I said before, it only works on the final window to be closed.

This is a bit of an X/Y problem and indeed, rebooting shouldn't really be considered as an option.
Instead, you should be looking at different options available for preserving your tabs across sessions. There are bunch of extensions that make this much easier. I stopped using Chrome's in-built features many years ago as they failed me even after system failures, which is their intended purpose.
For instance, I can recommend Session Buddy. It saves sessions on the fly, no matter if the browser crashes or exits cleanly. It can store both N snapshots taken every X minutes and mentioned browser closed type of groups. You can then restore these groups with a single click, at any time. Its recent version 4.x was a bit problematic, but it's getting into more and more stable state again.
